# Получить список маркеров с видимой области карты

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Так и не нашла - как понять, виден маркер пользователю или нет?
У меня есть список объектов на карте, хотелось бы его динамически менять при каких-то действиях пользователя - отображать только видимые.
Google Maps Android API v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это должно помочь :)

```
 public boolean isVisibleArea(final Marker marker)
    {
        final LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        final VisibleRegion visibleRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
        bld.include(visibleRegion.farLeft)
           .include(visibleRegion.farRight)
           .include(visibleRegion.nearLeft)
           .include(visibleRegion.nearRight);
        return bld.build().contains(marker.getPosition());
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает)
Мне тут недавно сказали, что число маркеров может вырасти до 2-3 тысяч. У меня сейчас уже подтормаживает слегка, а потом что будет? =(
Никак по-другому не решается?
Такая несправедливость - в iOS в гугл картах есть отдельный метод - получить все видимые маркеры, а в родном Андроиде нет =(

Comment: @tayrinn  данная проблема решается гуглением :) 
есть прекрасная статья от самого Google https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=ru&csw=1      
есть библиотека, которая реализует описанное в статье от Google https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/    
Так что не стоит унывать, Google уже обо всем позаботился